# Fix XSLT Numeric Cell Output to Excel as String

Tags: excel, xslt, filemaker

I am using an XSLT template to convert and format some output from FileMaker to Excel. It works perfectly for all but one column. The data is numeric, but must be output as a string in the format NN.NN. The data field is entered as, for example, 04.13, but when output to Excel, displays as 4.13. There are some cases where the user has input 04 13 (which oututs correctly as it cannot be parsed as a number) but where the user has entered the data correctly into filemaker (the field is Text), i.e. 04.13, I need to ensure the output data remains in the correct format.
I have tried the following, but it does not appear to work as expected - the output file still shows the column values as numbers, ie loses the leading zero:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$xlFieldName='d_Oracle_Task_Code'">
        <xsl:variable name="OracleTaskCode" select="fmp:DATA" />
        <xsl:value-of select='format-number(OracleTaskCode, "00.00")' />                            
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

I'm not worried about the cases where the input is missing the decimal point seperator, only ensuring the values are output as text.

Comment: Doesn't prefixing the value with an apostrophe make it a text?

Comment: It does yes. @michael.hor257k. How would I apply that via te XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was the order in which I checked. I could not get the XSLT to apply the formatting or append the apostrophe until I made my when block the first one in my choose block.

```
<Style ss:ID="xlTextStyle">
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
</Style>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$xlFieldName='d_Scheme_Task_Code'">
    <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">xlTextStyle</xsl:attribute>
        <Data>
            <xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">String</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </Data>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$xlFieldType='NUMBER'">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test...
```

I'm now getting the column values correctly formatted using the Text format.

Comment: There's probably a simpler way to approach this - but we don't see the context.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
```

then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($apos, format-number(OracleTaskCode, '00.00'))" />
```

---

Another option worth trying would be to define the cell contents as data type *string*:

```
<Data ss:Type="String">
    ....
</Data>
```

---

I am afraid I have no means to test either.

Comment: The field is already being set as type=String, as the format is not date or number - I have a Chose block which formats dates, numbers and anything else as a string. I'll give your idea a try - thanks.